# php replace all src atributes of img in file

Tags: php, html, dom

I have in page links like this:

**import.html**

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<img src="img/pic1.jpg" alt="" title="Picture 1" class="pic">
<img src="img/pic2.jpg" alt="" title="Picture 2" class="pic">
<img src="img/pic3.jpg" alt="" title="Picture 3" class="pic">
<p>random text</p>
<img src="img/pic4.jpg" alt="" title="Picture 4" class="pic">
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
//get file content
$html = file_get_contents('import.html');

function replace_img_src($img_tag) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($img_tag);
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    if (count($tags) > 0) {
        $tag = $tags->item(0);
        $old_src = $tag->getAttribute('src');
        $new_src_url = 'website.com/assets/'.$old_src;
        $tag->setAttribute('src', $new_src_url);
        return $doc->saveHTML($tag);
    }
    return false;
}

// usage
$new = replace_img_src($html);
print_r(htmlspecialchars($new));
```

**Goal:**

I want to replace **all** `src` attributes of `img` element in **import.html** file and **return file** with new image links. I managed to create replace one element.

How to edit this to go through whole file and replace all attributes and **return new import.html** with replaced `src`'s?

Comment: Normally you should use a foreach loop after you get the elements and save it in the $tags variable. something like foreach($tags as $tag). But I'm not sure what is in the $tags variable. what do you see when you run the code var_dump($tags); ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) method will return a `DOMNodeList` object containing all the matched elements. Currently, you're just modifying only one `img` tag. To replace all the `img` tags, simply loop through them using a `foreach`:

```
function replace_img_src($img_tag) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($img_tag);
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $old_src = $tag->getAttribute('src');
        $new_src_url = 'website.com/assets/'.$old_src;
        $tag->setAttribute('src', $new_src_url);
    }
    return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

Comment: I got `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::item()` on line `$tag = $tag_node->item(0);`

Comment: So it will return new `$html` with content where are all `src` of `img` replaced ?

Comment: @Ing.MichalHudak: Yes, (now) it will. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through all the tags and replace them. Not tested!

```
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
       $old_src = $tag->getAttribute('src');
        $new_src_url = 'website.com/assets/'.$old_src;
        $tag->setAttribute('src', $new_src_url);
        $doc->saveHTML($tag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($tags as $tag)
{
        $old_src = $tag->getAttribute('src');
        $new_src_url = 'website.com/assets/'.$old_src;
        $tag->setAttribute('src', $new_src_url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach to loop through all elements.

```
function replace_img_src($img_tag) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($img_tag);
    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
    foreach($tags as $tag){
        $old_src = $tag->getAttribute('src');
        $new_src_url = 'website.com/assets/'.$old_src;
        $tag->setAttribute('src', $new_src_url);
    }

    return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```